# How to split my list into two sections on navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I'm trying to split my navigation bar into two (with one part going left and the other right). When trying to get the items I want on the left side, I'm left with a small gap between the items and the wall. Where as, the right side hits the wall of the green and meshes.

**Kinda new to this posting thing so if you need more information on the code please be sure to respond*

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2dkhrjg8/2/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="table">
    <ul>
      <a class="" href=""><li class="main-nav">Home</li></a>
      <a href=""><li class="main-nav">about</li></a>
      <a target="_blank" href=""><li class="main-nav">where</li></a>
      <a href=""><li class="main-nav">team</li></a>
      <a href=""><li class="main-nav">Help</li></a>
      <li id="right-side" class="sign-in">Sign In</li>
      <li id="right-side" class="sign-up">Sign Up!</li>


    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#navbar{
  position: relative;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  background-color: green;
  }
.table{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  }
#navbar li{
  display: inline
  }
.main-nav{
  float:left;
  }
 #right-side{
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

Comment: Could you add an small image or description how it should look like ? Also the code from JS fiddle and here is a little bit different. By adding a `padding: 10px;`  to `#right-side` you would have the space between the elements.

Comment: Try padding-left: 0 on the <ul>

Comment: Oh, in the original post I meant I wanted the elements along the left side of the red, not the green one (my bad).

http://prntscr.com/hvwnv8 <--Here is picture of what I want it to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. The thing is that your `HTML` it's not semantically correct.

I would suggest using `flexbox` since it is super easy to do it.

Check the modified `HTML` and if I understood, this is what you want to achieve.

**Wish you happy styling and if need any more help just right**

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.main-nav:hover{
 
  background-color: #eff0f1;

}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">

        <ul class='navbar'>
          <li class="left-side">
            <a class="" href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="www.fdfd.com">About</a>
            <a target="_blank" href="#">Where</a>
            <a href="#">Team</a>
            <a href="#">Help</a>
            <input id="nav-search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
          </li>
          <li class="right-side">
            <a href="#" class="sign-in">Sign In</a>
            <a href="#" class="sign-up">Sign Up!</a>
          </li>
      
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This did it. I also have most of it styled, just wanted to simplify it for the question.